# Type cannot be serialized error when converting data to JSON stream

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a list of objects of type myClass:

```
List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>();
```

and I use the following code to get it into MemoryStream with ontention to write all the data to a json file:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs =new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(myClass));
            dcjs.WriteObject(ms, myList); <--ERROR HERE
```

The above gives me an error :

```
"Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[myClassToJSON.myClass, myClassToJSON, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' 
with data contract name 'ArrayOfmyClass:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/myClassToJSON' is  not expected. 
Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, 
by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."
```

If I remove [DataContract] attribute form befor the name of the class, I get a different error:

```
"Type 'myClassToJSON.myClass' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you  want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a   collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See  the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types."
```

My class is below:

```
namespace myClassToJSON
{
    [DataContract]
    class myClass
    {
       private string _name { get; set; }
       private string _type { get; set; }
       private string _value { get; set; }
       private string _units { get; set; }

       public string MName
      {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
      }

      public string MType
     {
        get { return _type; }
        set { _type = value; }
     }

     public string MValue
     {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
     }

     public string MUnits
     {
        get { return _units; }
        set { _units = value; }
     }

     public myClass(string sName, string sType,string sValue, string sUnits)
    {
       _name = sName;
       _type = sType;
       _value = sValue;
       _units = sUnits;
     }   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change declaration of `dcjs` as

```
DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs =new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<myClass>));
```

Because you are serializing a *List* of *myClass*